# Calculation of Gröbner basis.

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm not all that familiar with commutative algebra, so I need help with the calculation of a Gröbner basis. Let $ k $ be a field, and consider $ R = k[x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}] $. I need to find the reduced Gröbner basis for the intersection of the two ideals $ I = \langle x_{1} x_{3},x_{1} x_{4},x_{2} x_{3},x_{2} x_{4} \rangle $ and $ J = \langle x_{1} - x_{3},x_{2} - x_{4} \rangle $ of $ R $, with respect to the lexicographic monomial ordering $ x_{1} > x_{2} > x_{3} > x_{4} $. Thanks.

Comment: Just an inane comment, but after a couple of computations by hand, you'll probably want to learn to automate this by using Macaulay2 or CoCoA.

Comment: I don't know how to use those programs, but if you could help me churn out an answer using those, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Andrew how do they compare with Singular when the polynomials are structure functions about sp-graphs (describing whether the system works or not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt at computing this using Macaulay2. **Disclaimer:** I am still quite new to this, so I can't guarantee correctness (although I didn't purposely do anything wrong ;-) ). In particular, it seems Macaulay2 does not use Lex ordering by default, hence the optional command in the definition of $R=k[a,b,c,d].$

It appears that we obtain $(b^2d-bd^2, b^2c-bcd, ad-bc, abc-bc^2, a^2c-ac^2)$ as the reduced Groebner basis for the intersection $I\cap J.$

i1 : R=QQ[a..d, MonomialOrder => Lex]

o1 = R

o1 : PolynomialRing

i2 : I=ideal(a*c,a*d,b*c,b*d)

o2 = ideal (a*c, a*d, b*c, b*d)

o2 : Ideal of R

i3 : J=ideal(a-c,b-d)

o3 = ideal (a - c, b - d)

o3 : Ideal of R

i4 : K=intersect(I,J)

```
                    2       2   2                      2   2       2
```

o4 = ideal (a*d - b*c, b d - b*d , b c - b*c*d, a*b*c - b*c , a c - a*c )

o4 : Ideal of R

i5 : gens gb K

o5 = | b2d-bd2 b2c-bcd ad-bc abc-bc2 a2c-ac2 |

```
         1       5
```

o5 : Matrix R  <--- R

Comment: Hi Andrew! Thank you so much. Actually, after you made your comment, I realized that Wolfram Alpha does a pretty good job at calculating Gröbner bases. I obtained the same answer as you. Anyway, you have the honor of the best answer for your wonderful help! I'll make an effort to learn how to use Macaulay2.

Comment: Dear @HaskellCurry, haha, you are most welcome! Actually, I like to use Wolfram Alpha, but I never thought of using it to compute a Groebner basis, so I'm glad to know it can do that! I'm also glad that we got the same answer! Cheers